# Best practices for handling and representing dynamic changing data in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, graph-databases

I have a tool in which a user can define variables in multiple units. I store all the time-series or real-time data in a different database (not graph database), but I store all the metadata in a graph database, which are typically related to one time configuration. As a concrete example in a simple form

A user can define distance in kilometers or miles, an instance of Distance class and provide its dimensions and units as:

```
:distance1 a :Distance .
:distance1 :hasUnit :Kilometer .
```

If the user changes the same instance from kilometer to miles, I can update the instance as:

```
:distance1 a :Distance .
:distance1 :hasUnit :Mile.
```

However, when I retrieve all the time series data, how would I differentiate between the data corresponding to Mile unit and the data corresponding to Kilometer Unit. I can store the units in the time series database, but it defeats the purpose of using an ontology and being able to semantically provide the necessary information in automated fashion. I would like to know the best standard practices in that direction.